# Semantic UI Segment sizing issues

Tags: html, css, web, semantic-ui

Hey guys so i'm simply trying to Size the segment only around the content and not have it fill the entire width of the page. Ive tried everything and i just cant get it to. How do i go about resizing the segment? do i need to put it into another div? Or is there some simple semantic fix?

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.13/semantic.min.css">    



<div class="ui segment">
   
    <div class="ui middle aligned grid child">

  <div class="column">
    <div class="ui center aligned page grid">

      <div class="eight wide  column">

        <div class="ui two column middle aligned very relaxed stackable grid">
          <div class="ui vertical divider">
            Or
          </div>

          <div class="column">
            <div class="ui form">

              <div class="field">
                <label>Username</label>
                <div class="ui left icon input">
                  <input type="text" placeholder="Username">
                  <i class="user icon"></i>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="field">
                <label>Password</label>
                <div class="ui left icon input">
                  <input type="password">
                  <i class="lock icon"></i>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="ui blue submit button">Login</div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="center aligned column">
            
            <div class="ui big green labeled icon button">
              <i class="signup icon"></i> Sign Up
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>



      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Add `compact` class to your segment as seen in their [kitchen sink](https://semantic-ui.com/kitchen-sink.html#segment).

```
<div class="ui compact segment">
...
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Applying `display: inline-block` on your segment will make it only take up as much space as it needs.

In your example this results in elements squishing themselves into an unnecessarily narrow size. Try applying the `min-width` property to either the `segment` itself or other elements you feel are important.